# Worldlines and Lie Derivatives

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, geodesics

I've been reading through [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1140/epjc/s10052-023-11232-4), and there is one small part that I was hoping someone can help me understand better. If you care to, you can read the paper for more context, but broadly speaking one has the following setup:

(i) One has some spacetime manifold (in this case a Schwartzschild black hole) with metric $g_{\mu\nu}^{\text{(bald)}}$, some specific vector field $\zeta^\mu$, and the 4-velocities of light rays $p^{\mu\text{, (bald)}}$ on this space.

(ii) One generates another metric $g_{\mu\nu}^{\text{(hairy)}}$ using the Lie-derivative along $\zeta$ in the following way:

$$g_{\mu\nu}^{\text{(hairy)}}=g_{\mu\nu}^{\text{(bald)}}+\mathcal{L} \underset{\zeta}{} \ g_{\mu\nu}^{\text{(bald)}}.$$

(iii) Similarly, one has that the 4-velocities of light rays with this new metric are related to those with the original metric in the same way:

$$p^{\mu\text{, (hairy)}}=p^{\mu\text{, (bald)}}+\mathcal{L} \underset{\zeta}{} \ p^{\mu\text{, (bald)}}.$$

(iv) Finally, the geodesic equations for each of this metrics can be written in terms of the above 4-velocities in the following way:

$$\frac{d\overline{\gamma}^\mu}{d\lambda}=p^{\mu\text{, (bald)}} \quad\text{and}\quad \frac{d\tilde{\gamma}^\mu}{d\lambda}=p^{\mu\text{, (hairy)}},$$

where $\overline{\gamma}^\mu$ and $\tilde{\gamma}^\mu$ are the worldlines (geodesics) of light rays in the original space and the "hairy" space, respectively.

(v) They suppose that the worldlines of the "hairy" space are small deviations of the original "bald" worldlines, ie $\tilde{\gamma}^\mu=\overline{\gamma}^\mu+\delta\gamma^\mu$ for some small $\delta\gamma^\mu$.

With that out of the way, the question I have is:

> They claim that one must have $\delta\gamma^\mu=\zeta^\mu$. From the above information we of course have that
> $$p^{\mu\text{, (bald)}}+\frac{d\delta\gamma^\mu}{d\lambda}=\frac{d}{d\lambda}(\overline{\gamma}^\mu+\delta\gamma^\mu)=\frac{d\tilde{\gamma}^\mu}{d\lambda}=p^{\mu\text{, (hairy)}}=p^{\mu\text{, (bald)}}+\mathcal{L} \underset{\zeta}{} \ p^{\mu\text{, (bald)}}$$
> from which we obtain
> $$\frac{d\delta\gamma^\mu}{d\lambda}=\mathcal{L} \underset{\zeta}{} \ p^{\mu\text{, (bald)}}.$$
> It's not clear to me why this implies that $\delta\gamma^\mu=\zeta^\mu$. I assume that it's something obvious and that one can see it fairly immediately from rewritting the above as something like
> $$\frac{d\delta\gamma^\mu}{d\lambda}=\mathcal{L} \underset{\zeta}{} \ \bigg(\frac{d\overline{\gamma}^\mu}{d\lambda}\bigg)=\frac{d}{d\lambda}\bigg(\mathcal{L} \underset{\zeta}{} \ \overline{\gamma}^\mu\bigg),$$
> but I can't quite see why. Again, I assume this is obvious -- it's just a matter of my lack of experience/knowledge/understanding of some basic differential geometry on manifolds -- but can someone help shed some light on why this is true?

*As a sidenote: mathjax seems to not like subscripts following a mathcal -- I tried to make things as visually similar to what I wanted to type as I could, but if someone knows how to actually put the $\zeta$ as a subscript of $\mathcal{L}$, then of course feel free to edit it and delete this comment.*